# Looking For Resources on Separating Iron, Silicon Dioxide, and Sodium Chloride

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, reference-request

I am working on an experiment and lab report for my high school chemistry course where I am given a vial with a mixture of Ferrum, silicon dioxide, and sodium chloride. I need to figure out how to separate these three without causing any chemical change to occur to any of them, and then find the percent of each in the original mixture. I think that I could figure out the percentages pretty easily with some math, but I have no idea where to start with the actual separation process. I've looked online for resources to cite, but all of them go way over my head. For context, this is the second week of chemistry, and almost no one in the class has taken chemistry before. We just finished learning the difference between pure substances and mixtures. If you have any suggestions for resources that I will actually be able to understand or any tips for research/experimentation, I would be really happy.
Thank you, and apologies if this is out of the scope of this site.

Comment: "I have no idea where to start" unfortunately this just the thing you *should* have and write in your question.

Comment: @Meerkat, What is the approximate size of silicon dioxide? Is it sand by chance?

Answer (score 2):

This answer will assume that all the 3 substances are in solid state. First, we know that Iron, $\ce{Fe}$ as a pure metal can be attracted by a magnet, while $\ce{SiO2}$ and $\ce{NaCl}$ can't. A magnet can then separate the $\ce{Fe}$ from the other two.

Then, we also know that $\ce{SiO2}$ is insoluble in water while $\ce{NaCl}$ is soluble in water. So we can pour water into the mixture of these two substances, mix, and filter. You can obtain the filtrate as dissolved $\ce{NaCl}$ in aq form and $\ce{SiO2}$ as the residue in solid form.

Answer (score -8):

This is one of those silly experiments trying to teach something. Let's play the Game. Ferrum! To separate materials, compounds, elements one must learn as much as possible about their pertinent properties. the rule is that you must not chemically change anything. That means that you must already know what a chemical reaction is, very advanced! and the difference between chemical and physical properties and that you probably have to work with the physical properties. The first thing is How much do you have and what physical properties can you use to measure how much you have. What is the definition of matter? What in that definition can you use to determine how much matter you have then use the appropriate property or perhaps more than one. Examine the sample carefully. A point here must you use the entire sample or a representative sample? Is the sample mixed? If not the job can be easier. If they are not mixed or there are few of each visual separation may be possible [Pasteur's method read about him and optical isomers] size shape and color are physical properties a microscope and time will help here. [If you are lucky there is only one particle of each.] That probably won't work but it might give you a limited sample of each to test. Now you must investigate other properties. Since you have identities, look up these materials and find out whether they are elements, compounds, metal, molecular or ionic etc. and learn about their properties. You must look for differences that you can exploit with materials and equipment on hand or reasonably obtainable. Be prepared to defend that your method is physical. If possible work with a small representative sample after determining the total amount of material, then measure a precise sample for each and prorate the totals. Good Luck When done you will know more about this than your teacher.

Comment: you have written an indigestible text worm :/

Comment: Just how is someone, who has no idea how to start, to accomplish a task without doing some reading and research. Oh yes  someone should them instead of giving them a chance to learn how to look up something themselves. The goal is to learn chemistry not learn a recipe.